# How to open dialog - popup from action menu liferay

Tags: java, liferay

How to open dialog - popup from action menu liferay?

I trying to open dialog from action menu of search container, but I can't catch id of icon. What I can do?

Comment: What sort of code/approaches have you already tried?

Comment: I have not code for this problem. I want to catch Id of icon in action menu but it is automatic generate, and dynamic.

Comment: Please share the code regarding menu.